# 2 charts in one page with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create 2 charts in one page. Both work fine when are alone. But when I put both scripts in the same page, the last one always overrides the first.

My code is like this:

```
<script>
 ... chart ...
</script>

<script>
 ... chart 2 ...
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
<script>
 ... chart ...


 ... chart 2...
</script>
```

What should i do?

Comment: "What should i do?" - Add more detail to your question. :)

Comment: Please provide a code reference for your problem as a fiddle snippet/link.

Comment: Are you using the same place/container for your charts?

Comment: Provide more details. We cant solve it until you provide the sufficient detail

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code for 2 different charts in same script or different. it depends on you and your requirement. But, to have 2 highcharts to be displayed in one page you need to have different containers (divs) for different charts.

Comment: right one we can set two different names of div and according ly in jquery